# problem with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

i declared a NSMutable array and assigned some values to it .

```
.h
NSMutableArray *imageDetailsFromCategory;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imageDetailsFromCategory;

.m
@synthesise imageDetailsFromCategory
```

in ViewDidLoad:

```
imageDetailsFromCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//assigning object to Array..working fine.showing two images.
imageDetailsFromCategory = [self  getImageDetailsFromCategory:generatedString];
```

i had one problem that solved now. i have a problem that  is i am passing this array to **StaticCategoryWithMultiImagePopOver** class.

```
StaticCategoryWithMultiImagePopOver *staticCategoryWithMultiImagePopOver = [[StaticCategoryWithMultiImagePopOver alloc] init];

[staticCategoryWithMultiImagePopOver setParentImageDetailsArray:imageDetailsFromCategory];
```

in StaticCategoryWithMultiImagePopOver.h

```
NSMutableArray *nsmResult;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *nsmResult;
```

.m

```
@synthesize nsmResult

-(void)setParentImageDetailsArray:(NSMutableArray *)imageDetailsFromCategoryFromParent{
    nsmResult=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    nsmResult=[imageDetailsFromCategoryFromParent retain];

    }
```

the passed array hold a class object with some string variables  at each index.

so i am getting this through the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView15 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView15 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // if (cell == nil) {
    // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it


    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    SymbolTalkEntry *symbolTalkEntry = [[SymbolTalkEntry alloc]init];

    symbolTalkEntry =[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *imageNme = symbolTalkEntry.fileName; // *this line*
```

the above line is getting error.

array shows the count but the objects are out of scope..cant get the values ...

can any one tell me how can i access it...may i know what is the problem with me...

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**(its working fine)

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView15 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView15 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // if (cell == nil) {
    // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it


    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    SymbolTalkEntry *symbolTalkEntry = [[SymbolTalkEntry alloc]init];

    symbolTalkEntry =[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *imageNme = symbolTalkEntry.fileName;

    [symbolTalkEntry release];
    //Display image from app bundle
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",imageNme]]; 

    cell.imageView.image= [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
    return cell;


}

-(NSInteger)number
```

Comment: Is StaticCategoryWithMultiImagePopOver your table view data source? Or what file is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in?

Comment: why do you always `alloc init` if you are going to point to another object afterwards?

Comment: -[__NSArrayM fileName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81c5d80'

Comment: Sorry, this code seems wrong all over. I'd suggest with a good book on Objective-C.

Comment: You obviously get an NSArray returned from your call to `[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, not a SymbolTalkEntry (or maybe SymbolTalkEntry is a subclass of NSArray) 
In either case, you should get a ton of warnings from the compiler for this code, read them.

Comment: Wait. What?  You are hitting the filesystem for every cell that is displayed?  That seems like it'd be a huge performance hit.

Comment: It is nor relevant, that you write your code in Xcode, while you should tag it cocoa-touch, as you are using thats framework interfaces and classes. This tag is more accurate that tagging it iphone or ipad, as it referrers directly to the technology you are using and not the the devices, that can be used with other technologies as-well like webapps or non-apple frameworks as monoTouch for example.

Comment: and this is true for all your questions about iPhone development. please fix it, as people, who might want to help you and future readers will find your question more easily. and the people interested in how to use and set up xcode might be annoyed of unrelated question tagged so.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
nsmResult=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
nsmResult=[imageDetailsFromCategoryFromParent retain];
```

and this

```
SymbolTalkEntry *symbolTalkEntry = [[SymbolTalkEntry alloc]init];
symbolTalkEntry =[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

are memory leaks.

About your problem: the object you get by

```
symbolTalkEntry =[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

seems not to have a property fileName.

I think you should read a good book about Objective-C and Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the problem of the class which is inside the array.

I changed my class as this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface SymbolTalkEntry : NSObject {

 int categoryId;
 NSString *runModeType;
 NSString *sceneCategory;
 NSString *fileName;
 int isDefault;
 int sortX;
 int pathId;// 0 for appbundle 1 for document directry


}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *runModeType;;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *sceneCategory;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *fileName;

-(id)init;

-(void) setCategoryId:(int) ctgId;
-(int)categoryId;

-(void) setRunModeType:(NSString *)rmType;
-(NSString *) runModeType;

-(void) setSceneCategory:(NSString *)scCategory;
-(NSString *) sceneCategory;

-(void) setFileName:(NSString *)Flname;
-(NSString *) fileName;

-(void) setIsDefault:(int) isDeft;
-(int)isDefault;

-(void) setSortX:(int) srtX;
-(int)sortX;

-(void) setPathId:(int) srtX;
-(int)pathId;
@end
[5:05:00 AM] Shamsudheen TK: #import "SymbolTalkEntry.h"


@implementation SymbolTalkEntry
@synthesize runModeType;
@synthesize sceneCategory;
@synthesize fileName;


-(id) init{
 categoryId = 0;
 runModeType = @"";
 sceneCategory =@"";
 fileName = @"";
 isDefault = 0;
 sortX =0;
 pathId =0;
 return self;
}
-(void) setCategoryId:(int) ctgId{
 categoryId = ctgId;
}
-(int)categoryId{
 return categoryId;
}

-(void) setRunModeType:(NSString *)rmType{

 if (runModeType != rmType) {  
  [runModeType release ];
  runModeType = [rmType retain];
 }
}
-(NSString *) runModeType{
 return runModeType;
}

-(void) setSceneCategory:(NSString *)scCategory{

 if (sceneCategory != scCategory) {
  [sceneCategory release];
  sceneCategory = [scCategory retain];
 }
}
-(NSString *) sceneCategory{
 return sceneCategory;
}

-(void) setFileName:(NSString *)Flname{

 if (fileName != Flname) {
  [fileName release];
  fileName = [Flname retain];
 }
}
-(NSString *) fileName{
 return fileName;
}

-(void) setIsDefault:(int) isDeft{
 isDefault = isDeft;
}
-(int)isDefault{
 return isDefault;
}

-(void) setSortX:(int) srtX{
 sortX =srtX;
}
-(int)sortX{
 return sortX;
}

-(void) setPathId:(int) srtX{
 pathId = srtX;
}
-(int)pathId{
 return pathId;
}

-(void)dealloc{
 [categoryId release];
 [runModeType release];
 [sceneCategory release];
 [fileName release];
 [isDefault release];
 [sortX release];
 [pathId release];
}
@end
```

and set the values using the set methods that I wrote (eg: `[classobj setCategoryId:1]`).

now  out of scope is solved.....